# Java abruptly terminates when hasNextInt() encountered the end of input

Tags: java, stack, java.util.scanner, terminate

I'm trying to make stack. I used debug tool in Eclipse, and found the code terminates when `hasNextInt()` encountered the end of input. the below code terminates at 14th while loop, and 18th statement of the code `if(sc.hasNextInt()) {`. I also thought about JVM memory, but this code is not recursive, and the size of array is only 20!...

Here is input, I copy and pasted it to console (last "top" doesn't operate..) >>

```
14 push 1 push 2 top size empty pop pop pop size empty pop push 3 empty top
```

Here is the code>>

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class User_Stack {
    final static int SIZE = 20;
    static int[] array = new int[SIZE];
    static int where = -1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test; int input=0, result=0, tc=1;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        /*input the number of test cases*/
        int test_case = sc.nextInt();

        while(tc <= test_case){
            /*input what will do with Stack by String*/
            test = sc.next();
            /*what is pushed is input by Integer*/
            if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
                input=sc.nextInt();
            }
            /*call function by test String*/
            switch(test){
                case "push":
                    push(array, input);
                    break;
                case "pop":
                    System.out.println(pop(array));
                    break;
                case "size":
                    System.out.println(size(array));
                    break;
                case "empty":
                    System.out.println(empty(array));
                    break;
                case "top":
                    System.out.println(top(array));
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void push(int[] array, int x){
        if(where+1==SIZE) return;
        array[++where]=x;
    }
    public static int pop(int[] array){
        if(where==-1) return array[where--];
        else return -1;
    }
    public static int size(int[] array){
        return where+1;
    }
    public static int empty(int[] array){
        if(where==-1) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
    public static int top(int[] array){
        if(where==-1) return array[where];
        else return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `Scanner` waits for the next input token to know whether it is an `integer` or not and as it reached the end of your input, it waits for ever. You should move `sc.nextInt()` directly into the `push` as next:

```
while(tc <= test_case){
    /*input what will do with Stack by String*/
    test = sc.next();

    /*call function by test String*/
    switch(test){
        case "push":
            push(array, sc.nextInt());
            break;
        case "pop":
            System.out.println(pop(array));
            break;
        case "size":
            System.out.println(size(array));
            break;
        case "empty":
            System.out.println(empty(array));
            break;
        case "top":
            System.out.println(top(array));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding if(sc.hasNext) might not be helpful then.. Thanks!! I cannot think the Scanner waited next inpt. I'll try it!

Comment: yes I'm afraid that `if(sc.hasNextInt())` is not helpful in your case

Answer (score 0):

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566773/how-to-use-nextint-and-hasnextint-in-a-while-loop) is explaining why we cannot use .hasNextInt() in while loop.
Java scanner class method .hasNextInt() doesn't stop before the end of input.
The end of input for .hasNextInt() is ^Z which is not triggered by general key input.
It was the reason this code caused while to wait forever.