# why the next statement after the while loop doesn't get executed

Tags: java, while-loop

I am supposed to get the product of the integer entered by user util a number that is less than 1 is entered, and print the product. But when the program does nothing after I enter the numbers. How can I fix this.

Here is the code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter integers: "); 
    int num = 1; 
    int product = 1; 
    while(input.hasNextInt() && num>=0){ 
       num = input.nextInt(); product = product*num; 
     } 
    System.out.print("Product: "+product); 
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter integers: ");
  int num = 1; int product = 1;
  while(input.hasNextInt() && num>=0){
   num = input.nextInt();
   product = product*num;
   
  }
  System.out.print("Product: "+product);
  
  
  }

Comment: Hi Nate. As Amer said, please share your code as text. I suggest you check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to help you get started. A properly formatted question will get answered a lot quicker.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566773/how-to-use-nextint-and-hasnextint-in-a-while-loop

Comment: I edited my question so you guys can see the code

Answer (score 1):

First, your test `num>=0` is not a test for ending the loop when "a number that is less than 1 is entered", since `0` is less then 1 but won't end the loop.

Second, the test of `num` is done *after* `num` has been applied to `product`. You don't want that.

So you need to test `num` *after* getting it, but *before* applying it to `product`. If less than 1, you want to end the loop, which you can do with a `break` statement.

Also, it is generally bad style to put multiple statements on a single line.

```
System.out.println("Enter integers:");
int product = 1;
while (input.hasNextInt()) {
    int num = input.nextInt();
    if (num < 1)
        break;
    product *= num;
}
System.out.println("Product: " + product);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `while` loop keep running forever. So that's why it do not print anything.

Try this instead:

```
 while(input.hasNextInt() && num>=0){ 
   num = input.nextInt(); 
   product = product*num; 
   System.out.print("Product: "+product); 
 }
```

EDIT: Try to enter the number less than `0` then your  `while` loop should terminate.

Comment: I've tried what you said but that's not what I need. this is what I need: for example, I enter 2,3 and -2, I want the program to print 6 for the product.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter integers: "); 
    int num = 1; 
    int product = 1;
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            num = input.nextInt();
            if(num < 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            product = product * num;
        } catch(InputMismatchException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number.");
            input.nextLine();
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Product: "+product);
}
```

Comment: 1) Code without explanation is less helpful. 2) It is generally better to use `hasNextInt()`, rather than using exceptions. See [Defensive Programming vs Exception Handling?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/139171/202153)

Comment: @Andreas That is your opinion. Also if they need an explanation they can ask and I will explain it.

Comment: @Andreas also way to link to a `python` question...this is **java**.

Comment: The purpose of StackOverflow is to provide a repository of answers to questions, for the benefit of the general public. Your answer is not just for the person who asked the question, but for everybody who will find the question in the future when searching for similar problems. Please consider that when answering questions.

Comment: @Andreas there are multiple answers and other similar questions. If they can't find what they are looking for in my answer I'm sure there are plenty more options.

Comment: "Defensive Programming vs Exception Handling" is a *programming* topic. The language is of minor concern. Did you notice that the Python question accepted a .NET answer? It is equally applicable to Java. But you're right. It is an opinion, though one that is generally accepted.

Comment: @Andreas it doesn't change the fact that it is an **opinion**. People have different styles. It doesn't make one way right vs. another way.

Comment: And I'm allowed to leave a *comment* based on an opinion. Besides, I never said you're wrong. I used the word "generally", with link to article backing my "opinion".

Comment: Sure you can: `while (! hasNextInt()) { tell user input is bad and prompt again }`