# While loop wont stop running

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I have a while loop that's supposed to end when there are no more integers to be read. For some reason, it continues to keep checking (or at least I believe so) and won't return the print statement. My sample input would look like,

> 20 21 22 23

I've tried `hasNextLine()` before `hasNextInt()`, try/finally blocks and closing the scanner as well as reading through the forums.

If I phrased/formatted the question wrong or if there's another resource I haven't come across yet I would appreciate some feedback. I'm really just trying to learn.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    x = 0;
    in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (in.hasNextInt()) {
        x = in.nextInt();
        reverse(x);
        beautiful(x, reverse(x), y);
    }

    printCount(count);
}
```

Comment: When you read input from the standard input, the input never ends (the Scanner always waits for new input to be entered). You should require some special input to be entered in order to quit the loop.

Comment: Adding non integer values will break the loop, e.g `20 21 22 23 A` .

Answer (score 0):

in.hasNextInt() read data continuously. So you should use break; with appropriate condition  after your requirement complete to stop this.

Answer (score 0):

After these lines

```
    while (in.hasNextInt()) {
        x = in.nextInt();
```

insert the line

```
        if (x == 0) break;
```

and the loop will stop after entering `0` - you may, of course, choose another number for stop, i. e. `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many ways to solve this, but this one on my mind:

1. create a second scanner and pass to it your first scanner input `new Scanner(in.nextLine());`
2. create a while loop and go through until no numbers left. `sc.hasNextInt()`

Answer (score 0):

Your input should be terminated in some manner. 1 2 3 4 and 1 2 3 4 5 are both valid inputs as  scanner can't decide where to end on its own. It can be assumed that the number sequence is terminated by EOF character Ctrl-Z on windows and Ctrl-D on unix.

For more help on this look in to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566773/how-to-use-nextint-and-hasnextint-in-a-while-loop)